# ckeditor in browserify: home dir error

Tags: ckeditor, browserify

in `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
        "ckeditor": "./public/ckeditor/ckeditor.js",
        "bootstrap": "./public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"
      }
```

in source `browserify` `coffee-script` file:

```
$  = jQuery = require 'jquery-browserify'
ckeditor = require 'ckeditor'
jqueryCkeditor = require '../ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js'
$('#Info').ckeditor()
```

Errors in chrome browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4042/config.js?t=E7KD
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4042/skins/moono/editor.css?t=E7KD
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4042/lang/en.js?t=E7KD
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined ckeditor.js:219
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4042/skins/moono/editor.css?t=E7KD
```

Seemingly `ckeditor` cannon find its home directory: `/ckeditor`. How to help it?

## Update

working source code:

```
$ = jQuery = require 'jquery'
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/ckeditor/'

ckeditor = require 'ckeditor'
jqueryCkeditor = require '../ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js'
$ ->
    CKEDITOR.replace("Info")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to specify the path manually - http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = './public/ckeditor/';
```

Comment: Are you sure that you set that variable before including CKEditor? Because I'm nearly sure that something should change if CKEditor script could access that variable? Maybe you need to make sure that it's really global (so use `window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` or something like that)?